# HttpClient as singleton in dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

On the full framework there was a pattern that came out making HttpClient a singleton. This is because the existing connections could be reused, however on the full framework there were dns caching issues when doing this. Mostly when you would run httpclient as a singleton on the full framework it would cache the dns results, and you would have to use ServicePointManager to force it to refresh once in a while.

Now dotnet core LTS currently does not have ServicePointManager, so my question is. Can you run HttpClient as a singleton in dotnet core and have it respect DNS updates?

Comment: not directly related to your question, but it looks like `ServicePointManager` is coming back in .NET Core 2.0 https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Net.ServicePointManager

Comment: I have had many issues in the past with Windows Server not respecting DNS updates. How did you determine that this was a .NET issue and not an issue with Windows?

Answer (score 6):

I am quoting a post from the link below

> "Unfortunately, there's no way to do this with .NET Core today.
>   Either ServicePointManager should be brought over to .NET Core or similar equivalent functionality should be enabled some other way."

Here is the link that might be worth checking: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11224

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using HTTPClient as a singleton and injecting it into the controllers in my .NET Core APIs.
I can confirm that ServicePointManager exists in .NET Core Runtime **2.0.5**.

I'm using the following, after I've created the request to solve DNS issues.

```
Uri vRequestUri = new Uri ("https:api.example.com/....");
HttpRequestMessage vRequest = new HttpRequestMessage (HttpMethod.Post, vRequestUri);

ServicePoint vSP = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint (vRequest.RequestUri);
vSP.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000; // 1 Minute
```

For those who are not aware of the DNS problem, the following article would be informative http://byterot.blogspot.com.tr/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using the new SocketsHttpHandler

```
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
{
     ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
     PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) //https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26331
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler){};
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be fixed in dotnet core 2.1, currently available in preview.